# How does a SpellChecker Automatically generate correct Spellings

Tags: javascript, php

So I am trying to implement a spell check for some of the input texfields on a webpage. Mostly for city names and postal codes. I have an idea of how to it's going to work and am researching some algorithms and pspell_check() functions but the question I have is:

These forms are using PHP to submit information. Is it possible to suggest word corrections for a textfield before a user submits the form? specifically without using AJAX.

My thought process is I would use a JS function to check the textfields and compare the typed word to the existing entries in the API. I just can't figure out if it's possible without Using AJAX and without reloading the page.

Comment: how can PHP get hold of the data **BEFORE** the data is submitted? PHP cannot time travel. Feel free to implement a spell checker in JS, but that's a rather huge chunk of data to ram down someone's browser's throat.

Comment: Do you mean in a sort of autocomplete way? Similar to the suggestions that come up when entering a google search, but with spell corrections?

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too but my superior is against using AJAX for some reason so I thought I'd just check to see if someone had any ideas

Comment: Yeah, Autocomplete would be perfect! but again I don't think doing it without AJAX is a viable solution

Comment: @H.H. Your superior probably shouldn't be your superior if they are not willing to use proper tools for the job, especially without a solid reason. You need Ajax to do a realtime lookup as you type. I, personally, would do an AJAX option (if it doesn't take too much extra time) then do a non AJAX solution (not too sure exactly what that would be) but that would probably seal the deal on Ajax.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to convince him now to consider AJAX. From what I can see he's a brilliant engineer and I am sure he has his reasons for not wanting to implement JQuery and AJAX. I am new to this field so I can't question his decisions without a proper understanding of his reasoning.